# Capitalize HTML, XML, etc

Tags: support, edits, capitalization

I have a question about editing. When I edit, I am in the habit of capitalizing certain acronyms. Mainly HTML, XML, and CSS. However, I see these un-capitalized so often that I was wondering if they don't need to be capitalized. I personally think it makes the site seem more professional, but I may be wrong about this. Should they be capitalized?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/is-it-time-to-do-something-about-spelling-and-grammar.

Comment: YES!!! But, if you're going to do it make sure you fix **EVERYTHING** that's wrong. Capitalise I and change teh to the etc.

Comment: Also, please change "java" or "JAVA" to "Java", thanks ;-)

Comment: @Ben I mainly do it when I'm already editing a post, and if I'm not, I can usually find something else to change. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a fairly minor, but completely valid, edit. I'm not sure I'd say go ahead and edit posts just to capitalize these acronyms, but if you're in there editing anyawy, definitely go ahead and fix them.

Correct usage is to capitalize them, but it's not egregious enough to go change all cases (although I've noticed it is sometimes a bit easier to read when they are capitalized correctly, but that might just be due to the post in general looking better after a substansive edit).