# Add a dismissable spell check warning before posting a question

Tags: feature-request, editor

There already is a suggestion to [Please add a spell checker to the Markdown editor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3932/188615), but since that is solved better by the browser itself, I suggest this:

There is a lot of work involved for moderators to simply correct spelling.
This could be minimised if SO would better **warn** **before posting a question** with lot of spelling mistakes.

I know, there is already the message, if something is wrong:

> This question body does not meet our quality standards. Please make
>   sure that it completely describes your problem - including what you
>   have already tried - and is written using proper grammar.

At first, I could not submit [this question at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50894885/add-better-spelling-errors-check-to-the-stackoverflow-site), because of this warning. That is fine. Then I added some more correctly spelled text and the warning was gone. Although there are a lot of mistakes still.

There should be a **dismissable warning**, if your question still contains spelling mistakes, like

> Submit anyway. The mistakes are made on purpose.

This message should only come, if there are still spelling mistakes left, although the current checking algorithm said it would be ok.

*Related idea:* [Is it time to do something about spelling and grammar?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/is-it-time-to-do-something-about-spelling-and-grammar?rq=1)

Comment: If you vote,a comment would be nice

Comment: I voted it up. I disagree your suggestion, because I think the quality minimum enforced here is really low, and anybody not wanting to follow it, don't deserve such an escape path. But the reason of the downvotes was not this. They voted you down because *you asked a "do something differently" question*, and this was also my reason to vote you up - exactly this attitude what is really missing from the MSE, in my opinion.

Comment: [What do votes mean on Meta? Why was my well-written post downvoted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635)

Comment: I disagree that the warning should be dismissable.

Answer (score 7):

Least in theory, spellcheck isn't something that could/should be handled on the platform side. No one ever does it, and in many cases, the spelling mistake could be key to the problem.

As far as SO goes - you're going to see many things that *are not* words get flagged unless you built a 'code'-specific spellcheck engine. And had it smart enough to read codeblocks. And then had it monkeywrenched 'cause people keep putting inappropriate things in codeblocks.

SE's famous for low friction. It's a gift, since folks can get used to the basics quickly, and a curse 'cause not all new users get the way we do things.

And at the end of the day, it's not just for mods - the review queues encourage reviews of new user questions. If it's just spelling (as opposed to grammar) - it hardly takes longer than the time to read a question to fix.

Also, spellcheck isn't a panacea. I'm vaguely infamous for getting my its and it's confused and... spellcheck doesn't catch that.

In a sense, while it's tempting to baby our users and put rails in place to keep them from wandering off, its not always the best option.

I agree with the intent here, but I don't think it's a great use of resources to reinvent something every single modern browser has.